# Return statement in nested if function

Tags: ios, swift

I have been struggling with something for a while.
How can I return something in a nested if function?
The function below has the task of finding out if the userProfile has a verified card or not, if verified == 1 (true) then return true, else return false.

```
func userHasVerfifiedCard() -> Bool{
    let userDocument    =   users.documentWithID(Meteor.userID!)
    if let card         =   userDocument.valueForKey("profile")!["card"] {
        print("has card")
        if let verified = card!["verified"] as? Int {
            print("card.verified as Int")

            if verified == 1{
                print("card.verified == 1")
                lastFourCreditCardLbl.text = card!["last4"] as? String
                return true
            }else {
                return false

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your method won't return anything, if `if let card` won't work. But it must return a bool in any case.

```
func userHasVerfifiedCard() -> Bool {
    let userDocument    =   users.documentWithID(Meteor.userID!)
    if let card         =   userDocument.valueForKey("profile")!["card"] {
        print("has card")
        if let verified = card!["verified"] as? Int {
            print("card.verified as Int")

            if verified == 1 {
                print("card.verified == 1")
                lastFourCreditCardLbl.text = card!["last4"] as? String
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it's helps..!

```
func userHasVerfifiedCard() -> Bool{
        let userDocument    =   users.documentWithID(Meteor.userID!)
        if let card         =   userDocument.valueForKey("profile")!["card"], verified = card!["verified"] as? Int where verified == 1 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is hard to debug